# What do these statements mean in C++/CX?

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-cx

These are the statements

```
this->SizeChanged += ref new SizeChangedEventHandler(this, &MainPage::MainPage_SizeChanged);

Scenarios->SelectionChanged += ref new SelectionChangedEventHandler(this, &MainPage::Scenarios_SelectionChanged);

//These lines were in MainPage Constructor.
//Scenarios is the name of a ListBox
```

What do these two lines do?

What are `MainPage::MainPage_SizeChanged` and `MainPage::Scenarios_SelectionChanged`?
There are two function with this name that I can see but then wht there are no `()` in the function call?
Also why are they preceded by &?
And how can they be used as argument if their return type is void?

In the two lines, why is += used and not only =? What would happen if = is used?

Comment: For the `&`, look up "Pointer to member function" in your favorite C++ book. For the `+=` look up [Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh755799.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

These lines are subscribing to events. For example, `SizeChanged` is an event, `SizeChangedEventHandler` is a delegate type (similar to function pointer, but is also contains reference to class instance) and `MainPage_SizeChanged` is an event handler.

There are no `()`, because *it's not a function call*. The function `MainPage_SizeChanged` won't be called when you execute that line, it will be executed every time the `SizeChanged` event is raised. And the `&` is used because that's how function pointers are created in C++.

If you used `=` instead of `+=`, your code wouldn't compile. You can't *set* an event, you can only subscribe (using `+=`) and unsubscribe from it (`-=`).